# How to fail the seed job when using the Jenkins Job DSL plug-in

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

I'm using the Jenkins Job DSL plug-in and configured a seed job that is a parameterized build. I would like to fail the build if someone forgets to fill in one of the required parameters. I have the following at the top of my DSL script:

```
def expectedParams = [
  'BRANCH_NAME',
  'FALLBACK_BRANCH',
  'FOLDER_NAME',
  'FOLDER_DISPLAYNAME',
  'MAIL_TO'
];


boolean envChecksPass = true;
expectedParams.each {
  if (! binding.variables.get(it)?.trim()) {
      println "This script expects the $it environment variable to be set."
      envChecksPass = false;
  }
}

if (! envChecksPass) {
  // TODO: SET THE JOB STATUS TO FAILED
  return false;
}
```

How do I complete the TODO bit? Obviously I can throw an Exception here, but it seems a bit ugly. What is the preferred/best practice way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Throwing an exception is currently the preferred way. If you throw a `javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslException` the stack trace will be suppressed and only the message will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be to exit with a non zero code, which will mark the job result as a FAILURE:

```
if (! envChecksPass) {
  // TODO: SET THE JOB STATUS TO FAILED
  exit 1;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

in Jenkins pipelines it is better to use 'error' step

```
if (! binding.variables.get(it)?.trim()) {
    error "This script expects the $it environment variable to be set."
}
```

you will see the following output in the log (without stack stace)

```
ERROR: This script expects the USER environment variable to be set.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: This is "Job DSL" which is separate from pipeline/workflow. `ERROR: (seed_job.groovy, line 63) No signature of method: seed_job.error() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [attempted error string]`